# Can i build an add on to MSN LIVE?

Tags: msn-messenger

Is there a way i can build an add on to (MSN) Messenger Live? I heard its been done by something called MSN PLUS but i havent tried it and have a feeling it uses hacky methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there is one often used add-on called Messenger Plus (some don't use it because of suspicious optional bundled software).

[This looks like a good starting point](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowsLiveMessengerAddin.aspx).

(also, I think Windows Live Messenger have dropped the *MSN* prefix)